# testing network performance, speed and stability for domestic connection to internet

Tags: osx, networking, network-monitor

I need to connect to the internet from home and I would like to have software to test the connection, in terms of speeds and stability. I know that there are many webpages that allow one to test the speed of the network, but I would like to find something that would give me more information about the stability of the network.

I have experienced for other networks that the connection may be extremely unreliable, in the sense that it may be relatively fast, but with many interruptions, disconnections/reconnections.
I know that I can ping some address from the terminal, and there is also some webpage utility that does the same, and see if the network is dropping, but I would like to know a step further from this.

The motivation is that for my work I need to connect to a remote server through a VNC connection, so I need a stable and fast network. Now I have to change apartments and with the collaboration of the neighbour (that has a fast connection), I would like to test the network, in order to evaluate the network in the new building.

Moreover, I would like to know if there is software that is able to collect data about the stability of the network over an entire day, and show the trends as a function of the time.

Answer (score 0):

- [Cacti](https://www.cacti.net/)

It is a toolkit with extensive capabilities for graphically displaying and analyzing network performance trends that can be used to monitor almost any monitored metric presented in a graph.
[image]

- [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/)

It is a full-blown network and system monitoring tool that combines several functions in one web console. It can be configured to monitor and collect data from a wide variety of servers and network devices, providing maintenance and performance monitoring for each facility.
[image]

- [Observium](https://www.observium.org/)

Observium works great as a virtual machine, so it can quickly become the main tool for obtaining information about the status of servers and networks. This is a great way to add automatic discovery and graphical representation to a network of any size.
[image]

All of them are good, I hope one of them will help you.